# How to print "Good Morning" to the console at 9am every morning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I want to write a program that runs every morning at 9 AM using crontab that will print out the message "Good Morning, Cam".

Here is what I'm currently trying:

Crontab:

```
5 * * * * /Users/cameronbass/Desktop/Play/Ruby/hello_world.rb
```

Program:

```
Puts "Good Morning, Cam"
```

Error message from cron:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/cameronbass/Desktop/Play/Ruby/hello_world.rb: Permission denied
```

Is this possible with Ruby?

Comment: The permissions of your script are incorrect. What is the output of `ls -l /Users/cameronbass/Desktop/Play/Ruby/hello_world.rb`?

Comment: Even so, it's important to understand that you will not see any output from this. Cron is going to run your script in another session, and its output will not be visible to you

Comment: `puts` not `Puts`. The latter will raise `NameError: uninitialized constant Puts`.

Comment: To see it in your terminal you would have to do something like \`wall "Good Morning, Cam"\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run a script without permissions to execute it. If crontab runs this as `cameronbass`, then just do the following:

```
cd /Users/cameronbass/Desktop/Play/Ruby/
chown cameronbass hello_world.rb # set cameronbass as an owner
chmod 700 hello_world.rb # give read, write and execute permissions to owner
```

and try again.

Comment: While this will fix the permission problem it won't fix the problem of the output not appearing on the user's console.